# yield return vs. return IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, ado.net, ienumerable, sqldatareader, yield-return

I've noticed something curious about reading from an `IDataReader` within a using statement that I can't comprehend. Though I'm sure the answer is simple.

Why is it that whilst inside the `using (SqlDataReader rd) { ... }` if I directly perform a `yield return` the reader stays open for the duration of the read. But if I perform a direct `return` calling a SqlDataReader extension method (outlined below) that the reader closes before the enumerable can be actualized?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>(this SqlDataReader rd)
{
    while (rd.Read())
        yield return rd.ConvertTo<T>(); //extension method wrapping FastMember

    rd.NextResult();
}
```

To be absolutely clear of what I'm asking, I'm unsure why the following are fundamentally different:

> A fleshed out example, as per @TimSchmelter's request:

```
/*
 * contrived methods
 */
public IEnumerable<T> ReadSomeProc<T>() {
    using (var db = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.someProc", db);

        using(var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(rd.Read())
                yield return rd.ConvertTo<T>(); //extension method wrapping FastMember
        }
    }
}


//vs
public IEnumerable<T> ReadSomeProcExt<T>() {
    using (var db = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.someProc", db);

        using(var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            return rd.Enumerate<T>(); //outlined above
        }
    }
}

/*
 * usage
 */
var lst = ReadSomeProc<SomeObect>();

foreach(var l in lst){
    //this works
}

//vs
var lst2 = ReadSomeProcExt<SomeObect>();

foreach(var l in list){
    //throws exception, invalid attempt to read when reader is closed
}
```

Comment: I think your question is answered in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) article on what 'yield' does.

Comment: That's because a method with `yield return` is turned into a state machine.  It would be better to not mix lazy initialization inside of `using` statements for this very reason.

Comment: You should show part of the code where you read the data. To be clear, the first version allows to read while the second throws an exception that the reader is closed?

Comment: @vipersassassin:well, both use `yield return`, that's why OP wonders why he gets different results.

Comment: @TimSchmelter And yet reading that article still explains the difference in behavior, because they both use `yield` differently.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hey Tim! Long time follower of your posts. Thanks for reaching out. To be clear, the two `using`'s are executed in isolation. I've modified the question to be more demonstrative of that.

Comment: @johnny5 Both solutions defer reading the results for an equal duration.  Both solutions call `ConvertTo`, not just one, and they both do so at the same time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **Summary:** Both versions of the method *defer*, but because `ReadSomeProcExt` doesn't defer execution, the reader is disposed before execution is passed back to the caller (i.e. before `Enumerate<T>` can run). `ReadSomeProc`, on the other hand, doesn't create the reader until it's been passed back to the caller, so it doesn't dispose the container until all its values have been read.

When your method uses `yield return`, the compiler actually changes the compiled code to return an `IEnumerable<>`, and **the code in your method will not run until other code starts iterating over the returned `IEnumerable<>`**.

That means that the code below doesn't even run the first line of your `Enumerate` method before it disposes the reader and returns a value. By the time someone else starts iterating over your returned `IEnumerable<>`, the reader has already been disposed.

```
using(SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
    return rd.Enumerate<T>();
}
```

But this code would execute the entire `Enumerate()` method in order to produce a `List<>` of results prior to returning:

```
using(SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
    return rd.Enumerate<T>().ToList();
}
```

On the other hand, whoever's *calling* the method with this code doesn't actually execute the method until the result is evaluated:

```
using(SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
    while(rd.Read())
        yield return rd.ConvertTo<T>(); //extension method wrapping FastMember
}
```

But the moment they execute the returned `IEnumerable<>`, the `using` block opens up, and it doesn't `Dispose()` until the `IEnumerable<>` finishes its iterations, at which point you will have already read everything you need from the data reader.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Will accept as soon as timer runs down. If I understand correctly, it's a matter of deferred execution. The extension method `Read<T>` returns a "contract" to iterate whereas `yield return` directly iterates upon invocation.

Comment: @PimBrouwers `Read` does not defer execution, no.  Both of your solutions defer calling `Read` until the returned enumerable is actually iterated. *Neither* of them reads the values upon invocation.

Comment: @PimBrouwers: I think you may understand correctly, though the way you put it might be a little ambiguous. `yield return` does not iterate when the method is called, but it directly iterates when the returned `IEnumerable<>` is evaluated. `Read()` is not deferring execution: `Enumerate()` is.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: sorry that's what I meant. The yield inside `Read<T>()` is deferring execution, return an iterator block, not a materialized collection.

Comment: @PimBrouwers: You mean the `yield return` inside `Enumerate<T>()` is deferring execution.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: sorry yes! my apologies, the method is named differently locally hence my confusion.

Comment: @PimBrouwers The other version, that doesn't use `Enumerate` *also* defers execution of the reading.  As mentioned earlier, *neither* of these methods are going to do any reading of this query when you call the method.  It's not that just one of them defers the reading.  This is because both methods use iterator blocks to yield the read values.

Comment: @Servy that doesn't explain why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @PimBrouwers Indeed it doesn't.  The deferring of the actual reading of the values has nothing to do with why one works and one doesn't, because both defer the reading of the values identically.  The difference between the two is how they defer disposal of the reader (and also execution of the reader), not how they defer actually doing the reading.

Comment: @Servy interesting... so the `while(rd.Read())` version actually defers the disposal of the reader?

Comment: @PimBrouwers Both solutions use `while(rd.Read())` in them.  The working solution is the one that defers disposal of the reader until the reading is actually done.  You can simply step through the code with a debugger to see when each line (including the dispose call) runs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151976/discussion-between-pimbrouwers-and-servy).

Answer (score 1):

It's because the "yield return" will return one element and continue the iteration, while  the "normal" return will finish the invocation.